# How to create navbar with css shapes using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create the navbar like below.

[image]

I have used background image for navbar its working but it will be displayed in tab and mobile view like [this](http://garyahlskog.com/)

FYI,
Tab and mobile responsive will be like below (only design not text)...

[image]

I need to create this without background image. Can you please help me...

Comment: what have you tried? the link which you have added is totally different

Comment: That url having background image like above. but its repeated..

Comment: One more thing i need this without background image...

Comment: you want create the angled shape which is between the logo and nav?

Comment: Yes, you are right (only the white shape in image)..

Comment: read about linear-gradient ... `background:linear-gradient(-45deg,red 50%,blue 0)` --> try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the shape i have used `skewX`

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/74775/pexels-photo-74775.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
  background-size: cover;
}

.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  border: none;
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-brand:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -100%;
  background: #fff;
  left: -500px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}

.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav {
  float: right;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```